# How to create constructor with array

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

How to convert this simple constructor from Data class in such a way that its arguments will be stored in arrays?

```
public class Data {
    private int number;

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }


    public Data(int number){
        setNumber(number);
    }
}
```

Comment: change your instance variable to array variable

Comment: Do You want to change Constructor argument also to an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change like

```
public class Data {
private int [] number;

public []int getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(int[] number) {
    this.number = number;
}


public Data(int[] number){
    setNumber(number);
}
}
```

change instance variable to `int array` and `setter` method argument as `int array` also `constructor's` argument should be `int array` and also `getter` method should return `int array`.

Comment: Is this part correct?
public []int getNumber() {
    return number;
}

I think it should looks like:
int[] getNumber()

I use NetBeans and I see errors when I use your code.

If there is no problem, could you tell me how to work with this constructor correclty?
int[] data = new int[3];
        data[0] = 1;
        data[1] = 1;
        data[2] = 2;
        
        Data number = new Data(data);
        
        System.out.println(number[0].getNumber()); // not work

Answer (score 0):

You can use constructor with `varargs` parameter. So, you will be able to hold the parameters in an array.

```
public class Data {
   private int [] number;

   public []int getNumber() {
      return number;
   }
   public void setNumber(int... number) {
    this.number = number;
   }    
   public Data(int... number){
    setNumber(number);
   }
}
```

Comment: What will be your setNumber()?

Comment: Sorry, missed that, now added :)